# Same error :Databinding System.Data.DataRowview

Tags: vb.net

Im using datagridview in asp.net.When im trying to add row using footer template in find error coming up.I have corrected syntax and column is in Database.

```
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="lblMembershipName" runat="server" width ="150px" **Text='<%# Eval("MembershipName")%>' >** </asp:Label> </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMemshipName" runat="server" width ="150px" Text='<%# Eval("MembershipName")%>' ReadOnly = "true" > </asp:TextBox> </EditItemTemplate> <FooterTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipName" runat="server" Width = "150px"></asp:TextBox> </FooterTemplate> <ItemStyle Width="30px" /> </asp:TemplateField>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MembershipName")%>
```

Comment: Still the error persists.When i add the data its inserted by it shows server error."Databinding System.Data.DataRowview" and it highlights this line "<asp:Label ID="lblMembershipName" runat="server" width ="150px""

Comment: try `<%# Container.DataItem.MembershipName%>` if its not work then some thing other issues D:).

Comment: Thanks for all ur help.It was my mistake while selecting the table after inserting.Thank u for help.  This is the right one.<%# Eval("MembershipName")%>

Comment: Another help pls.When i load the aspx page. I want those footer template visible.Even there is no data in the table.         Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load, UpdatePanel1.Load                     If Not IsPostBack Then                                        BindData()                                                       End If                                                             End Sub